# jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(jobName) returns null

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have the following method in a groovy file called by my Jenkinsfile:

```
@NonCPS
def getJob() {
  def job = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(env.JOB_NAME)

  for (def build : job.builds) {
     echo "${build.number}"
  }
}
```

This method is then called in the pipeline script from within `node` and inside of a `stage`. However, when I build this in Jenkins, `job` is considered null and `job.builds` gives the following error:

**java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'builds' on null object**

Is there any way to get around this error?

Comment: `JOB_NAME <> fullName,` if using folders.

Answer (score 3):

You can access all builds using `jobBuilds=currentJob.getBuilds()` .
Please see below which will display the build nos.:

```
def currentJob = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(env.JOB_NAME)
def jobBuilds=currentJob.getBuilds()

for (def build : jobBuilds) {
    println ("Build no is : ${build.number}")
}
```